# How to use vlookup with the first entry being a list instead of a value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I have a data set like this:

```
apple 11 
orange 22
grape 33
```

And a list like this:

```
apple
grape
```

Is there anyway that I can look up (and sum up) the values in column B based on the sub-list? In this case, my sum will be 44

I tried index match and `vlookup` but can't seem to `lookup` using a list. I also Google extensively but all search results I got were related to `lookup` using multiple criteria (array) which I know how to do.

Please help?

In this case, it'd be easy to add up two individual lookups. However, in my real example, my list has over 10 values so it wouldn't be too efficient

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You want to introduce an OR statement into a conventional [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5). This can be accomplished by wrapping it in a [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616).

[image: SUMIF wrapped by SUMPRODUCT]

The formula in E4 is,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A:A, D2:D9, B:B))
```

This does not require CSE.

Comment: Thank you very much Jeeped! Appreciate the speedy response..haven't used SUMIF this way before